# Tests of basic JK trigger

Tags: logic, vhdl

I have an equation(sorry for poor formatting, couldn't find proper symbols):

> Q<sub>t</sub>x<sub>1</sub> ∨ !x<sub>1</sub>((x<sub>2</sub> ⊕
> x<sub>3</sub>) ∨ !x<sub>4</sub>)Q<sub>t</sub> ∨ (x<sub>2</sub> ∧
> !x<sub>3</sub> ∨ x<sub>4</sub>)!Q<sub>t</sub>)

Assuming this is JK trigger:

> C = !x<sub>1</sub>
>
> J = (x<sub>2</sub> ∧ !x<sub>3</sub> ∨ x<sub>4</sub>)
>
> K = (x<sub>2</sub> ⊕ x<sub>3</sub>) ∨ !x<sub>4</sub>
>
> Q<sub>t</sub>!C ∨ !x<sub>1</sub>(!KQ<sub>t</sub> ∨ J!Q<sub>t</sub>)

Schematic looks like this:

[image: schematic]

It translates perfectly, however, when I try to simulate this with this test:

```
clock_proc : process begin -- synchro signal
x1 <= '0';
wait for 4 ns;
x1 <= '1';
wait for 4 ns;
end process ;
reset_proc : process begin -- reset
reset <= '0';
wait for 4 ns;
reset <= '1';
wait ;
end process ;
test_proc : process begin -- triggers
 
x2 <= '0'; x3 <= '0'; x4 <= '0'; --write 0
wait for 10 ns;
x2 <= '0'; x3 <= '1'; x4 <= '1'; --save
wait for 10 ns;
x2 <= '1'; x3 <= '1'; x4 <= '1'; --write 1
wait for 10 ns;
x2 <= '1'; x3 <= '0'; x4 <= '1'; --save
wait for 10 ns;
x2 <= '0'; x3 <= '0'; x4 <= '1'; --inverse
wait for 10 ns;
x2 <= '0'; x3 <= '1'; x4 <= '1'; --save
wait for 10 ns;
end process ;
end TB_ARCHITECTURE;
```

All I get is this error:

> KERNEL: Error: KERNEL_0160 Delta count overflow. Increase the iteration limit using -i argument for asim or the matching entry in simulation preferences.
>
> Error: Fatal error occurred during simulation.

[image: signals]

I'm fairly unexperienced with triggers and don't really understand what might have caused the problem so I'd be more than greatful if anyone explained it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the actual VHDL source, delta cycle oscillations occur in zero time modeled JK flip flops either from lack of reset or from having matching delays in the the feed back path.  Notice this occurred for a negative edge of the clock with both J and K high and Q high and nQ low.  This is a zero delay feedback loop that will continue as long as clock is low.

Either used timed gate models, add a delta cycle delay on one feedback path (an intermediary signal) use an after delay on one of Q or nQ, or if both mismatch the delay. (`Q <= expression1 after 400 ps; nQ <= expression2 after 401 ps;`).  If you add matching delays you can actually see the accidental gated striking oscillator in action.

In reality if there's any chance the feedback paths can match precisely the device vendor will unbalance the delays by playing with trace width, length or transistor size.

You can get the same thing in a T flip flop zero timed VHDL model.